# Comment dire « below/above » en référence à une autre partie du texte ?

Tags: traduction, indications-de-lieu

> See the line **below** this

et

> See the line **above**

Comment les traduire ? *Voir la ligne **{below/above}** ça.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Le couple d'expressions qu'on utilise couramment est

> la ligne **ci-dessous** (below)
>   la ligne **ci-dessus** (above)

Comment: ...et complètement hors-sujet pardon, mais comme à chaque fois que je dois utiliser ou différencier above/below, pas moyen de m'y retrouver sans me chanter intérieurement le petit passage d'*Imagine* de Lennon (*no hell below us, above us only sky...*)

Comment: *be-low* = être dessous? *ab-ove* ~ over ? Ça ne t'aide pas?

Comment: Put it above/on top of = mets-le au-dessus/par-dessus. Put it below/underneath = mets-le au-dessous/par-dessous.

Comment: On pourrait aussi utiliser le latin "vide infra"/"vide supra" pour des textes académiques.

Comment: @YohannV. Oui, je sais que c'est un peu stupide ^^ Et *be-low* me semble très clair en effet, je ne sais pas pourquoi ces deux-là ne me viennent pas naturellement comme le reste. Pas important. :-)

Answer (score 5):

#### Contexte de la question

Dans un document, ainsi que ton exemple le suggère et que [Romain l'a répondu](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14116/7224), *ci-dessous* et *ci-dessus* sont les traductions habituelles.

> *See the line **below**.*
>   Voir la ligne **ci-dessous**.

---

> *See the line **above**.*
>   Voir la ligne **ci-dessus**.

C'est une tournure générique, utilisée telle quelle. Il est inutile de rajouter « ça ».

Si tu veux utiliser un repère dans le document, voici un exemple (note que la traduction de *below* et *above* change dans ce cas) :

> *See the line **below**/**above** the figure.*
>   Voir la ligne **sous**/**au-dessus de** la figure.

#### Contexte général

Dans la vie de tous les jours, on utilise plus généralement *en dessous* (ou plus simplement *sous*) et *au-dessus*.

> *The wires run **below** the surface.*
>   Les câbles passent **sous** la surface.

---

> *He lived far **below** his income.*
>   Il vivait bien **en dessous** de ses moyens.

---

> *There is a portrait of the Queen **above** my desk.*
>   Il y a un portrait de la Reine **au-dessus** de mon bureau.

Petit piège : les mots composés avec « au » (au-dessus, au-delà, ...) prennent un trait d'union, mais pas ceux composés avec « en » (en dessous, en deça, ...).

Comment: (+1) Belle réponse, très complète :-) Ma réponse à la va-vite de cinq heures du mat' allait à l'essentiel, mais c'est chouette que quelqu'un ait pris la peine de détailler et de clarifier.

Comment: merci beaucoup Chop :)
seul une clarification SVP: quelle est la difference entre "en dessous de" et "au-dessus de"?

Comment: @dragonml La signification : « en dessous de » signifie « _below_ », « au-dessus de » veut dire « _above_ ». La différence entre « en dessous de » et « sous » est liée au contexte. En règle générale (avec quelques exceptions peut-être), « en dessous de » = « _below_ » et « sous » = « _under_ ».